# Cucumber, calling Steps from other step. Best practise?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have a deep discussion today with a colleague. Is calling a step from another one considered a best practice? 
So, for example:

```
Given /a turtle/ do
  puts "turtle!"
end

Given /two turtles/ do
  step "a turtle"
  step "a turtle"
end
```

In my opinion, this means that you cannot change the feature files without check the whole project. So if I want to stay DRY, I prefer to use a "code" function (i.e. in Ruby) called from these steps.

```
def turtle do
   puts "turtle!"
end

Given /a turtle/ do
  turtle
end

Given /two turtles/ do
  turtle
  turtle
end
```

If I have no choice, I even prefer to duplicate code instead of calling other steps.

```
Given /a turtle/ do
  puts "turtle!"
end

Given /two turtles/ do
  puts "turtle!"
  puts "turtle!"
end
```

What is considered best practices, and why?

Comment: You're talking about [`nested steps`](https://www.relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/nested-steps)?  I'd suggest posting sample code, if possible.

Comment: I hear often to use called functions from steps, and to use multiple function calls in more generalized steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting steps is a really bad practice. You'll quickly get into a tangled mess if you do this. A good step definition is a one line call to a method. Anything else can get messy pretty quickly

Consider:

```
   When "I login" do
      visit login_path
      fill_in ...
      ...
      submit
   end

   When "I login as as admin" do
     visit admin_login_path
     fill_in ...
     ...
   end
```

see how immediately there is duplication. Now you could remove this by step nesting and passing parameters, but then you will end up with a really complex step definition that is hard to debug so instead just call a helper method

```
   When "I login" do
     login user: @i
   end

   When "I login as an admin" do 
     login user: @i, role: admin
   end
```

What we are doing here is using step definitions for only one simple task, translating a line in a scenario to a method call. All the complicated stuff is now in a standard method. Programming languages are great at dealing with complexity. When we write our login method, we will have all sorts of tools and techniques available to us so we can manage any complexity whilst keeping our code DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use like this

**Feature**

```
Given "2" turtles
```

**Step Definition**

```
Given / "(\d+)" turtles/ do | count |
  count.times.do
    puts "turtle!"
  end
end
```

Comment: I know. The example's purpose is to explain the question in a better way. The question is: calling steps from other steps is considered best practice?